# didSelectRowAtIndexPath when select can't turn to other pages

Tags: objective-c, didselectrowatindexpath

```
if(!_personViewController)
    {
        _personViewController=[[PersonViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PersonViewController" bundle:nil];
    }

    _personViewController.user=_user;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_personViewController animated:YES];
    [PersonViewController release];
```

This is my code. I just want to when select the row can jump to personViewController page but it seems bad.

Comment: PersonViewController is a class. You shouldn't be trying to release it...though that may not be related to your symptoms.  Can you set a breakpoint to verify that the code is actually being executed?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
//_personViewController.user=_user;
```

or

```
_personViewController.user=[_user retain];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check it whether you write navigation controller in  `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` and  it is AppDelegate.m file.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
       UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

        [self.window addSubview:[navControl view]];

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```